# Error: error getting endorser client for channel

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have download fabric samples and binaries in latest version v1.3.0-rc1.

while up the first network, by using following command:-

`./byfn.sh up -c mychannel -s couchdb`

Peer cant join the channel. Give the following Error:-

> > Having all peers join the channel...
> >
> > peer channel join -b mychannel.block
> >
> > res=1
> >
> > set +x
> >
> > Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I found a solution. recently fabric release their stable version v1.3.0. I have download the new fabric samples and binary and docker images for v1.3.0. 

Then it works fine. SO recommended to use fabric latest stable version v1.3.0.  

thank you.

Comment: Downloaded latest stable version 1.3.0. The problem persists. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that your cryptogen tool (the one you have setted in your path) is the one that you are using in your example, is very common to be pointing to an old version tool.

I highly recommend if you are going to restart everything to clean all your containers running

```
./byfn.sh -m down
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

After that re run the start command `./byfn.sh -c mychannel -m up -s couchdb -a`

If you are still having problems, maybe you can start with an easier example, I figured out how to setup a Fabric (v1.2) y two differents hosts using the basic network example.

[Setup hyperledger fabric in multiple physical machines](https://medium.com/1950labs/setup-hyperledger-fabric-in-multiple-physical-machines-d8f3710ed9b4)

Hope that this help!

Comment: I found a solution. recently fabric release their stable version v1.3.0. I have download the new fabric samples and binary and docker images for v1.3.0. Then it works fine. SO recommended to use fabric latest stable version v1.3.0. thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can have look at this [document](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html) to run fabric with multiple peers, because when you start you should start with the following command

```
./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a
```

while -a option will not work with latest branch for some issues so you should check out for branch which is specified in the document above.

Comment: I found a solution. recently fabric release their stable version v1.3.0. I have download the new fabric samples and binary and docker images for v1.3.0. Then it works fine. SO recommended to use fabric latest stable version v1.3.0. thank you